# XGBoost prints trees beyond n_estimator

Tags: decision-trees, xgboost

I have a XGBoost model with the following parameters

```
xgbc_final = XGBClassifier(objective="multi:softprob",
                           num_class = 2,max_depth = 60,
                           n_estimators = 512,
                           reg_lambda = 0.1214,
                           alpha = 0.9131,
                           gamma = 0,
                           colsample_bytree = 0.7,
                           colsample_bylevel = 0.8,
                           colsample_bynode = 0.7,
                           subsample = 0.6,
                           learning_rate = .01,
                           min_child_weight = 14,
                           random_state = 2020,
                           eval_metric = 'auc',
                           verbosity = 1)
```

Here, I only have `n_estimator = 512` but I noticed that when I try to print a decision tree greater than 511, I still get a plot

```
plot_tree(xgbc_final, num_trees=900)
```

I expected an error for **n_estimator greater than 511(if the trees are index from 0)**

Can anyone explain why it's spitting out trees for number greater than 512?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're doing multiclass classification, and xgboost does that by building parallel models for each class.  So the total number of trees is actually $512\cdot (\text{# classes})$.

I don't know what order those trees come in.  `plot_tree` calls `to_graphviz` which calls (after maybe `model.get_booster`) `model.get_dump`, which calls some c-level stuff I won't try to track down.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! If I were to guess, for class 0, index=511 is the last tree and for class 1, index=1023 is the last tree.